# Heritrix 3.2.x , how to read content from warc files ?

Tags: heritrix

Using Heritrix 3.2.x, i had crawled a website, Now i want to read the HTML content from the warc files created. Can anyone help ?
I tried using python warc tool and java based warc-tools.jar.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea what warc file consists, just use some kind of text editor. For graphical view, you need a tool like [webarchiveplayer](https://github.com/ikreymer/webarchiveplayer) or  [pywb](https://github.com/ikreymer/pywb) or [openwayback](https://github.com/iipc/openwayback).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried programming a reader using [JWAT](https://sbforge.org/display/JWAT/jwat-warc) or use the [JWAT Tools command line](https://sbforge.org/display/JWAT/Running+JWAT-Tools).

```
jwattools.cmd extract path.to.warc(.gz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same version of `Heritrix` you are using. For the playbacks, the `OpenWayBack` is used.

The `OpenWayBack` is bundled with `CDX-Indexer` which could be used to extract the contents which is written to a `CDX` file where you can obtain the `HTML` links etc.